# How to properly set up subfolders for each language and not break plugins?

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

We are launching a Shopware 6 website and want to acomplish the following URL strucutre:

https://example.com/de -> German Language
https://example.com/en -> English Language

We currently have tree entries in the the Storefront's domain configuration:

[image: Storefront configuration]

The problem here is, that the language switcher always defaults to the shortest (?) URL when switching stores, i.e. when switching from EN to DE, it picks https://example.com instead of https://example.com/de.

We have the entry (1) in the domain configuration, because without it, plugins break (they cannot properly generate their API URLs anymore).

Is this a problem in the plugins and should it be possible to just delete (1) or are we supposed to make the configuration differently?

Comment: Probably an issue with the plugins, as they probably expect that they can reach the store-api under the APP_URL, but that is not always true as in your case.
Do you know how the plugin genereates the API URLs?

Comment: Just remove the entry without /de and add a redirect to your web server that will point to /de or /en when the url without this addition is called.

Comment: Okay, I pinged the Plugin Vendor as well. Interesting part is, that it's two different plugins from different vendors which seem to cause those problems. So I was thinking I am wrong here :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments of @j_elfering and @mnaczenski I reported to the plugin vendor who released a fix very quickly.

I believe this is the important change in the module. It's not really accessing the store API but a normal controller:

diff:

```
-        window.router['example.widgets.topbar'] = '{{ url('example.widgets.topbar') }}';
+        window.router['example.widgets.topbar'] = '{{ seoUrl('example.widgets.topbar') }}';
```

So it is important to use the `seoUrl` helper instead of `url`

This seems to be a common mistake, as we are using a second extension (different vendor) with the same problem.